# Non-existence of pushout in homotopy category

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spheres, limits-colimits, path-connected

I want to show that $S^1_{(0)}\leftarrow *\to S^1_{(1)}$ has no pushout in the homotopy category without using Eilenberg–MacLane spaces.

In a first step, I want to show that *if* there is such a pushout, it must be homotopy equivalent to $S:=S^1_{(0)}\sqcup_0 [0,1]\sqcup_1 S^1_{(1)}$. Having this, it is easy to see that this cannot be a pushout.

In order to get the first statement, I call the pushout $X$ and construct a map $f:X\to S$ and $g:S\to X$.

1. $f$ is just a representant for the universal map arising from $S^1_{(i)}\to S^1_{(i)}$.
2. $g$ is constructed by from $S^1_{(i)}\to X$. Now the basepoints can be mapped to different points, but as the square commutes, they are in the same path component. Now we choose a *good* (see below) path $\gamma$ connecting these two. This completes the map $S\to X$.

[image]
By the universal property, it is clear that $g\circ f\simeq \mathrm{id}_X$. I want to proof that $f\circ g\simeq\mathrm{id}_S$. Of course, this depends on the choice of $\gamma$. To be precise, I need something of the following form:

> $\gamma$ can be chosen such that $f\circ\gamma:[0,1]\to S$ is the inclusion of the intervall.

This last claim looks so elementary that there must be an easy proof or counterexample, but I cannot find it.

Comment: So coproducts are one of the few colimits that the homotopy category does actually posses. (Products are another one). You might like to state exactly what homotopy category you are working in (i.e. based vs free).

Comment: I work in the homotopy category $\mathbf{hTop}$ of spaces with morphism free homotopy classes of maps $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{hTop}}(X,Y)=[X,Y]$. Furthermore, I am not looking for a coproduct (maybe you thought I want to describe a coproduct in the based version because the maps from the point are just the initial maps?) but for a pushout – are you sure this exists?

Comment: I thought you were working in $hTop_*$. Coproducts exist in the homotopy category as can be checked directly. The pushout of your diagram in $Top_*$ is the wedge and this pushout does exists in $hTop_*$. Of course the wedge is not the coproduct in the unbasd category $Top$.